# Vimperator: map <S-/> to /

Tags: vimperator

I want to change `/` key to `<C-k>` and `?` to `/`, therefore my ~/.vimperatorrc has these lines:

```
map / <C-k>
map ? /
```

The first line works but the second line doesn't make any change. I have tried using `<S-/>` or `<S-?>` instead but they still don't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can map `?` to `/` by escaping the `?`:

```
map \? /
```